# Inheritance of permission between the related models in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 3 models like bellow:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass


class PropertyPost(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='posts4thisowner',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Image(models.Model):
    prop_post = models.ForeignKey(
        PropertyPost,
        related_name='images4thisproperty',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The idea here is that the user can post many PropertyPost and each PropertyPost can have many images.

Things are working fine. My problem is in the permission.  I have set a set of permissions as follows for my PropertyPostDetail views, and no permission for the ImageDetail view:

```
class PropertyPostDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
 ...
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        custompermission.IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly,
        )

class ImageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    name = 'image-list'

class ImageDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    name = 'image-detail'
```

which I meant that only the post owner can mess around with its posts.

Now, because the image model is for the PropertyPost I expected that this permission carry over to the images as well. However apparantly any user can edit any image, which is obviously a flaw. 
My question is how could I set my image view to inherit permissions from its parent which is PropertyPost.

Comment: Can you add the `IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly` permission class?

Comment: I thought about this but It also has bigger flaw. because a user first creates a post and then adds images one by one, this means that owner of the image is one who CREATES the image not the one who creates the propertpost. What I am trying to say is when creating an image since everyone has readonly for others' posts then they can assign the image for any arbitrary post.  only good thing about `IsCurrentUserOwnerOrReadOnly` here is that once one created it no one can edit/remove it. it doesnt guarantee that the image is for the same post of the owner.

Comment: How can you identify the owner of the image without a owner field?

Comment: I copied your answer, and it looks like it is pretty close. `request.user == obj.prop_post.owner` is about right. request.user is the one who trys to add add the image and obj.prop_post.owner is the one who owns the post.perhaps I need an owner for the image, since at current status is still adding the picture

Comment: That's what i am asking, how can you get the owner of the imahe?

Comment: anyway, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, so hopfully there would be easier solution but here is how I resolved it. I tried here not to create an owner for image model, because image model has PropertyPost as its parent, which has an owner. So Image should inherit that owner:

```
class Image(models.Model):

    prop_post = models.ForeignKey(
        PropertyPost,
        related_name='images4thisproperty',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prop_post_owner=models.CharField(max_length=150,null=True,blank=True)
```

and this would be the serializer:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    prop_post = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=PropertyPost.objects.all(),
                                             slug_field='pk')
    prop_post_owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='prop_post.owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (
            'pk',
            'url',
            'prop_post',
            'prop_post_owner'
       )
```

this way my image model has an owner that is comming from the PropertyPost.

now at list level user can create an object and since it is not clear which object the user is going to select, so custompermisions will fail. Finally this is how I prevent non-owners from creating an image field for a property:

```
class ImageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
    name = 'image-list'
    ....
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        obj=PropertyPost.objects.get(pk=int(self.request.data['prop_post']))
        if self.request.user!=obj.owner:
            raise ValidationError('you are not the owner')
        serializer.save(prop_post_owner=self.request.user)
```